# bootstrap 4 form validation as the user types along

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4, addeventlistener

I recreated my problem in a simple index.php with 2 inputs and 1 button which redirects to page2.php.
I have BS-4 form-validation and the input tags have a regex pattern.

**Problem 1:** It does the validation ONLY after I click the button. Not as I type along.
**Problem 2:** When refreshing and not entering anything, the button redirects me to page2.php.

I think the culprit is : `addEventListener('load')` but I'm not sure since I'm new to PHP, JS, Bootstrap and to life in general...

*Would be very grateful for any idea!*

Here is the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  input[type="submit"]:disabled {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <form action="page1.php" id="myForm1" class="was-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" autofocus>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" autofocus>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        let currForm1 = document.getElementById('myForm1');
        currForm1.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (currForm1.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          currForm1.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to allow the form to be submitted when any of the inputs are empty, you need to add the `required` attribute to them, here is an example:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let currForm1 = document.getElementById('myForm1');
  currForm1.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (currForm1.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    currForm1.classList.add('was-validated');
  }, false);
  // Validate on input:
  currForm1.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
      if (input.checkValidity()) {
        input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
        input.classList.add('is-valid');
      } else {
        input.classList.remove('is-valid')
        input.classList.add('is-invalid');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  input[type="submit"]:disabled {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <form action="page1.php" id="myForm1" class="was-validation" novalidate="z">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" autofocus required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" autofocus required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my second problem. I'm still trying to have the validation work as I type in the text in the input fields. e.g. - if I type just one letter, I get no invalid/valid msg even though it's invalid (min 3 chars). I then click the button, the invalid messages appear and NOW the validation works as I type in the input fields. (check it out via "Run code snippet"). So, how can I make the validation mechanism work even before I hit the button?

Comment: @gadi That is not the default behaviour but you can add it, I will the snippet in my answer to show one way of doing it.

Comment: I need to add to your solution the same functionality but for a form that also has input, textarea and checkbox elements. Is it possible? (Should I open a new question for this...?)

Comment: @gadi Yes, it is possible, you can open a new questions. For `<textarea>` elements, you can just replace `currForm1.querySelectorAll('input')` with `currForm1.querySelectorAll('input, textarea')`. For `<input type="checkbox"/>` it is a little different, instead of listening for `input` events, you'll have to listen for `change` events.

Comment: Thank you for all your work. Couldn't make it work yet. I'll open a new question regarding how to add textarea, checkbox, email etc. to your solution.

Comment: Well, just found that it didn't work because **`TEXTAREA` does not except `PATTERN`** which is what I tried to validate it with.